# How to configure github native dependabot to use nexus repository for project updates

Tags: github, nexus, dependabot

I'm trying to configure a dependabot.yml for automatic updates for github native dependabot without success. Every attempt to access Nexus, I get an error of authentication, although the username and password are properly configured on dependabot secrets.
My config file is something like this:

```
    version: 2
    registries:
      maven-artifactory:
        type: maven-repository
        url: http://my_nexus_repository
        username: ${{ secrets.NEXUS_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.NEXUS_PASSWORD }}
    updates:
      - package-ecosystem: "maven"
        directory: "/"
        registries:
          - maven-artifactory
        schedule:
          interval: "daily"
```

The documentation is not very clear about options to configure Nexus and I would like to know if anyone knows how to do this.